# What are the requirements for landscape layout to work?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, landscape

So basically I created different xml layout for landscape mode, put it into folder res/layout-land, kicked off an emulator, pressed CTRL + F12 to change emulator's mode to landscape, started my app and ooops it still doesn't work. It still shows off in the portrait mode. What are other requirements to make this going. Do I have to tinker with R.java or activity's code onCreate  ?

Comment: many know which cntl button you are using...

Comment: Emulator bug. Use an emulator with a **2.2 "Froyo"** device - The only emulator that reacts to orientation changes properly. By the way, by pressing **7 on the numpad** you achieve the same orientation toggling than by using Ctrl+F11 and Ctrl+F12.

Answer (score -1):

Hit <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> , or <kbd>Home</kbd>, or <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, (not <kbd>NUMPAD 7</kbd> or <kbd>NUMPAD 9</kbd> like [the website](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) says) to rotate emulator.